# Local development with FB Login and collaborative Github workflow

Tags: facebook, git, workflow, collaboration, revision

My webapp is currently running off a shared googleDrive folder for easy updating and collaboration between a few developers. I am brining-on more developers though so I need a better workflow for revisions & conflict-free collaboration... I would like to use git[hub], but my app is using FB for login credentials which requires auth requests to come from my app's domain, so if my developers pull the git to develop on local machines there is no way to obtain OATH. Anyone know of a solution for this problem?

Comment: Is your application in development or is it live?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can run cheap [VM instance on Amazon](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/) (for example) for development purposes. Create FB token for it and share among the team. Perfect workflow, I think.
2. You can externalize FB token in properties file (according to your programming language/framework), ignore it in git, and allow each developer to have their own (however, this can break many logic inside app, not saying about need to configure an environment for all team members).

Also, beware that if you had you personal token in git once, it is stored **forever**. You may need to clean up you repo before sharing it with others.